# Creating a dictionary from xml

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary

Given this XML:

```
<dataroot>
    <TestTable>
        <Tag>tag1</Tag>
        <FName>t1</FName>
    </TestTable>
    <TestTable>
        <Tag>tag2</Tag>
        <FName>t2</FName>
    </TestTable>
    <TestTable>
        <Tag>tag3</Tag>
        <FName>t3</FName>
    </TestTable>
</dataroot>
```

How can I load it into a Dictionary so that if I look up "Tag3", it returns "t3"?

I have tried:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("ConfigItems.xml");
Dictionary<string, string> ConfigItems;
ConfigItems = doc.Descendants("TestTable").ToDictionary(v => v.Attribute("Tag").Value.ToString  (), v => v.Attribute("FName").Value.ToString());
```

But I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? What have you tried?

Comment: Those are not attributes, they are elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are [not attributes, they are elements](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp). This should work:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(s);
Dictionary<string, string> ConfigItems;
ConfigItems = doc.Descendants("TestTable")
  .ToDictionary(v => v.Element("Tag").Value,
                v => v.Element("FName").Value);
var item = ConfigItems["tag3"];
Console.WriteLine(item); // "t3"
```

An attribute would be like this:

```
<TestTable Tag="tag1" FName="t1" />
```

Comment: Yes, my bad.  As soon as I switched to element instead of Attribute, it works.  Thank you very much.

Comment: ToString is redundant

Comment: @Selman22 So it is! I copy/pasted the OP's code without looking at all of the details too closely. I've removed it now.